# Selecting second .prev eg .prev().prev()

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have a problem selecting the second `.prev()`

HTML:

```
<div></div> <- Set margin to 0;
<div></div>
<div id="interactive"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#interactive").prev().prev().css("margin", "0");
```

It's going to give CSS to both of them, i want the changes only apply for the first div.

Best Regards,

Comment: Is there any reason you can't give the div you are trying to access an id or class?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOvpdZ .`prev().prev()` returns the correct element, only the first div is affected

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="target"></div>
<div></div>
<div id="interactive"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#target").css("margin", "0");
```

This is better practice than `prev().prev()` and efficient

Comment: This is efficient way as prev().prev() require more processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/adp8qxyb/

```
<div id="interactive"></didv>
```

The Problem might be some syntax/markup errors in your HTML. Be sure every tag is well closed

Comment: Good answer, but bad explanation. perhaps you could be more explicit ;)

Answer (score -1):

Html:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div id="interactive"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var f;
for( f=0;f<document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;f++){
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[f];
  if(div===document.getElementById("interactive")){
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[f-2].style.margin="0";
  }
}
```

I have tested it!
It works also if there are more elements before the 3 divs!

Comment: This would only work if the page only has this 3 divs. It will not work in any other case.

Comment: it will work with all other elements the same as with div and mixed - i have tested it - it works

Comment: if there are more divs on the page, before theses, it will not work at all. It will choose a different div. I don't mean if the tag is different, I mean that if there are more elements on the page it will fail.

Comment: but he wants the first div!

Comment: No, man, he want to select two divs before the div with the `interactive` id. He is not showing the whole page, but you can be sure there are much more elements in its HTML.

Comment: There would be cases in which wouldn't also work. Please, don't take it amiss. It's simply that you're going through the hardest way to arrive to the solution. The question was really, really simple if you knew jQuery. And was directly related to jQuery, not to solving this particualr problem. Don't worry about my happyness, worry about yours! Be happy.